# Solve and explain diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

1. A Diophantine equation ax+by = c 
   always has a solution whenever a and b are relatively prime.
2. Find x ,y  such that    $$93x-81y=3  $$

Comment: Do you know Euclidean division algorithm ?

Comment: divide by 3 and you get : 31x -  27y = 1. Now you can solve it ?

Comment: yes i know findind the gcd of two number , then (m,n)=(n,m-tn) for any integer t

Comment: @YiyuanLee actually the current statement is valid as well. It doesn't say that if $a$ and $b$ are not relatively prime it will not have solutions.

Comment: how to show the first statment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide throughout by $3$.
You get $31x-27y=1$.
Now note that $gcd(31,27)=1$
Thus, by Euclidean algorythm there exist integers $p$ and $q$ such that.
$31p+27q=1$.
Compare to get values of $x$ and $y$.

You have,

$31=27(1)+4$

$27=4(6)+3$

$4=3(1)+1$

Thus you have

$1=4-3$

$=4-(27-4(6))$

$=4(7)-27$

$=7(31-27)-27$

$=31(7)-27(8)$.

Thus $31(7)+27(-8)=1$

Comment: I have done this  (31, 27) = 1

Comment: Do you know how to write gcd as a linear combination of the two numbers?

Comment: You have, 31=27*1+4.....27=4*6+3....4=3*1+1....thus you have 1=4-3=4-(27-4*6)=4*7-27=(31-27)*7-27=31*7-27*8. I hope you understand, it's a bit clumsy.

Comment: write clear solution if posibble

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: 1= 31(7) +27(-8)

Comment: 1=31(7) +27(-8)     .....       3 = 31(21) -27 (-24)  ....  where  651-648 = 3 which means  x = 21   and  y = -24

Comment: Exactly. Do you know that ax+by=c has a solution iff gcd(a,b) | c. Also gcd can be expressed as a linear combination of the two numbers. In your example gcd was 1 (after dividing by 3) and you found out the linear combination. This is the reason, a solution always exists.

Comment: or x = 7 and   y = -8

Comment: The answer is x=21 and y=-24

Comment: but question is 93x -81y = 3 so then value of x is 7 and yis -8

Comment: Oh, my bad. Yes, the answer is x=7 and y=-8.

Comment: thank for help i more plz, how we show the above statment

Comment: solve for the perticular solution

Answer (score 0):

Infinitely many solutions of the same.

$y=31k+8$

$x=27k+7$

or

$y=31k-23$

$x=27k-20$

Comment: what is the value of k it satisfies the initial solution

Comment: y = -8-93t   and x = 7+81t  now cjose the value of t which satisfies the initial equation

Comment: what is the value of t which satisfies the 93x+81y=3

Comment: Your question, I do not quite understand. Number "k" - can be any course. What we want.